# Trying to redirect when calling certain url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am trying to go to a certain folder in my project like www.example.com/example and have it redirect to a page inside that folder like www.example.com/example/signuppage.

Right now I am getting a 403 when going to the folder so I have it redirecting to another page. But when I put a redirect on that page to the one that I want it is telling me too many redirects.

Comment: could you share your best "try" code? You haven't put a lot of effort into your question

Comment: I edited it to explain more what I am doing.

Comment: have you checked www.example.com/example/signuppage. Is it redirects somewhere or shows needed page. 
Because one redirection should work fine.

Comment: If I go to www.example.com/example/signuppage it works just fine

Comment: Hard to say without code.
and why 403 (forbidden)  code returns?
Should be 301 or 302.

Comment: It looks like *directory browsing* is not allowed and there is no default page in `example` folder. 403 means `Access denied`.